# friends system php and mysql queries?

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering how best to layout my database for my friends system? I was going to do it like this,

```
 id (int) | friendID (int) | accepted (enum)
```

Which is how I think it should be done, just one question:

1. Upon a user confirming a request should I change the current row enum to yes and then insert another row for the user that confirmed it? ie;

   ```
   1 | 4 | yes
   4 | 1 | yes
   ```

Or is there a way I can pull both relationships from the one row without inserting another?

ie;

```
1 | 4 | yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think it is better to insert twice for each friend, since space is cheap, and you'll probably be adding friends less often than reading them. If you want to save space however, you can change the way you select the friends from:

```
select friendId from friends where id = $userId
```

to

```
select friendId, id from friends where id=$userId or friendId=$userId
```

then on the php side, you would check if friendId or id is the currently logged in user etc.

Comment: What do you mean by saving space?

Comment: I mean that when you have a friend and insert twice, you are making your table twice as long. This can allow you have to have faster read queries since you don't need the 'OR' in the where clause. However, if you intend to read often, you should definitely add an index on friendId, which will also cost some space.